How to set interaction behaviors from Style
I am repeating my code multiple times in XAML
Repeated code =
                    <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="50">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:TextBoxMaxValueBehavior MaxValue="4"/>
                            <behaviors:TextBoxNoLettersBehavior/>
                            <behaviors:SelectAllTextOnFocusBehavior/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>

Template code =
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <i:BehaviorCollection>
                        <behaviors:SelectAllTextOnFocusBehavior/>
                    </i:BehaviorCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

ERROR = 'The BehaviorCollection is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.
Invalid type: expected type is "DependencyProperty", actual type is Behavior Collection'.
My issue is in the Template code that I'm using... I thought that this could be easier.
Thanks for your time!

Does this answer your question? How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter

A simple resuable solution is to create a custom attached behavior that collects the interaction behaviors to apply them on the attaching object:
Usage example
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="InteractionBehaviorCollector.InteractionBehaviors">
    <Setter.Value>
      <InteractionBehaviorCollection>
        <TextBoxMaxValueBehavior MaxValue="4"/>
        <TextBoxNoLettersBehavior/>
        <SelectAllTextOnFocusBehavior/>
      </InteractionBehaviorCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

InteractionBehaviorCollection.cs
Create a collection that can be used in XAML:
public class InteractionBehaviorCollection : List<Behavior>
{
  public InteractionBehaviorCollection()
  {
  }

  public InteractionBehaviorCollection(IEnumerable<Behavior> collection) : base(collection)
  {
  }

  public InteractionBehaviorCollection(int capacity) : base(capacity)
  {
  }
}

InteractionBehaviorCollector.cs
Create the attached behavior that collects and applies the interaction behaviors:
public class InteractionBehaviorCollector : DependencyObject
{
  public static InteractionBehaviorCollection GetInteractionBehaviors(DependencyObject attachingElement) 
    => (InteractionBehaviorCollection)attachingElement.GetValue(InteractionBehaviorsProperty);

  public static void SetInteractionBehaviors(DependencyObject attachingElement, InteractionBehaviorCollection value) 
    => attachingElement.SetValue(InteractionBehaviorsProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionBehaviorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "InteractionBehaviors",
    typeof(InteractionBehaviorCollection),
    typeof(InteractionBehaviorCollector),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(InteractionBehaviorCollection), OnInteractionBehaviorsChanged));

  private static void OnInteractionBehaviorsChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {    
    if (e.OldValue is InteractionBehaviorCollection oldBehaviors)
    {
      BehaviorCollection interactionBehaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(attachingElement);
      foreach (Behavior behavior in oldBehaviors)
      {
        _ = interactionBehaviors.Remove(behavior);
      }
    }

    if (e.NewValue is InteractionBehaviorCollection newBehaviors)
    {
      BehaviorCollection interactionBehaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(attachingElement);      
      foreach (Behavior behavior in newBehaviors)
      {
        interactionBehaviors.Add(behavior);
      }
    }
  }
}


I've created a helper utility to allow a behavior class to be included in a style definition.
public class BehaviorForStyle<TTarget, TBehavior> : Behavior<TTarget>
    where TTarget : DependencyObject
    where TBehavior : BehaviorForStyle<TTarget, TBehavior>, new()
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledForStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabledForStyle",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(BehaviorForStyle<TTarget, TBehavior>),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledForStyleChanged));

    public bool IsEnabledForStyle
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledForStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsEnabledForStyleProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsEnabledForStyleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is bool newValue)
        {
            var behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(sender);
            var existingBehavior = behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => b.GetType() == typeof(TBehavior)) as TBehavior;

            if (!newValue && existingBehavior != null)
            {
                behaviors.Remove(existingBehavior);
            }
            else if (newValue && existingBehavior == null)
            {
                behaviors.Add(new TBehavior());
            }
        }
    }
}

Now the behavior class should descend from BehaviorForStyle<> rather than just Behavior<>
For example
public class BlockWindowAltF4CloseBehavior : BehaviorForStyle<Window, BlockWindowAltF4CloseBehavior>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.System && e.SystemKey == Key.F4)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

and usage in a style
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="help:BlockWindowAltF4CloseBehavior.IsEnabledForStyle" Value="True" />
    ...
</style>


Introducing a new base class for all behaviors is also a solution. Note that your solution is not backwards compatible with existing behaviors or 3rd party behaviors. I would also remove the remove the generic type parameter TBehavior from BehaviorForStyle as it is kind of awkward to force the inheritor to specify its own type.

I think using the Factoy Method pattern is more elegant in this context and simplifies the class signatures. You simply force the inheritor to override an abstract BehaviorForStyle.CreateInstance method that returns a fully initialized instance of the custom behavior. This also improves flexibility for the inheritor as he no longer is limited to a default constructor. He now has full control how to instantiate and even configure the behavior instance.

Thanks for your time, I will try it soon!

Define Attached Properties for Behaviors
First, you need to define attached properties in a separate class to manage the behaviors. Here's an example in C#:
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class TextBoxBehaviors
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseBehaviorsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "UseBehaviors",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(TextBoxBehaviors),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnUseBehaviorsChanged));

        public static bool GetUseBehaviors(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseBehaviorsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetUseBehaviors(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(UseBehaviorsProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnUseBehaviorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is TextBox textBox)
            {
                var behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(textBox);

                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    // Add your behaviors here
                    behaviors.Add(new TextBoxMaxValueBehavior { MaxValue = 4 });
                    behaviors.Add(new TextBoxNoLettersBehavior());
                    behaviors.Add(new SelectAllTextOnFocusBehavior());
                }
                else
                {
                    behaviors.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Use the Attached Property in XAML
Now you can use the attached property in your XAML to apply the behaviors to any TextBox:
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="50" behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.UseBehaviors="True"/>
    <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="50" behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.UseBehaviors="True"/>
    <!-- Add more TextBox elements as needed -->
</Grid>


This solution doesn't scale because the used behaviors are hardcoded into the attached behavior.

Thanks for the code, will try it later!
